# Does logic app performance depends on connectors?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

If we are using custom connectors in logic app, does the performance of logic app gets affected by the server which is hosting the connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the significantly most part, no.  The Connector will not affect the performance of the *LogicApp*.

But, a Connector will have a measurable effect on the overall performance of you App as a whole.  Meaning, you really need to consider the performance of any Connector and the Logic App separately.